# Android: Set popup window width same as achor view width

Tags: android, popupwindow

I am using constraint layout in which I have arranged views using flow.
 These views are added dynamically.
[image]

On clicking any of view a popup window should open like shown in the illustration below:
[image]

I have managed to show the popup window but it is not taking complete width of anchor view. This is how it is looking right now:

[image]

This is the snippet from my code which shows the popup window

```
anchorView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
val width = anchorView.measuredWidth
val height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT

val focusable = true
val popupWindow = PopupWindow(popupCardBinding.root, width, height, focusable)
popupWindow.showAsDropDown(anchorView)
```

How can I make it's width same as anchorView's width?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you're calling `measure` for the anchor view, but try measuring after the view has been drawn - using `UNSPECIFIED` doesn't always return the correct values, if you use `measure` too early:

```
anchorView.post {
  anchorView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
  val width = anchorView.measuredWidth
  val height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT

  val focusable = true
  val popupWindow = PopupWindow(popupCardBinding.root, width, height, focusable)
  popupWindow.showAsDropDown(anchorView)
}
```

If it doesn't work, try showing more code about how and when `anchorView` is created

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and couldn't find a good answer after searching for a while.
I ended up passing the Anchor View to the `PopupWindow's` constructor.

```
public TestPopupWindow(Context context, View anchorView) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context; 
        this.anchorView = anchorView;
        createView();
}
```

And setting the `width` during the view inflation.

```
private void createView() {
        View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.popup_window_layout, null); 
        this.setWidth(anchorView.getWidth());
        setContentView(view);
}
```

Simple and works for me